# the google map api doesn't works

Tags: javascript

the current location as well as the distance from a given coordinate is displayed as per the expectation but a location (given in coordinates) is not being displayed on the google maps on the web page. i have included the google maps api and the console doesn't shows any error. been banging my head for quite a while to solve the issue. any help would be highly appreciated.

```js
window.onload = getMyLocation ;

var ourCoords = {
 latitude: 47.624851,
 longitude: -122.52099
};

function getMyLocation () {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation , displayError);
 }
 else {
  alert("opps! no geolocation support.");
 }
}

function displayError (error) {
 var errorTypes = {
  0: "Unknown Error",
  1: "Permission Denied",
  2: "location is not available",
  3: "Request timed out!"
 };

 var errorMessage = errorTypes[error.code];
 if (error.code == 0 || error.code == 2) {
  errorMessage = errorMessage + " " + error.Message ;
 }
 var div = document.getElementById("accurateLocation");
 div.innerHTML = errorMessage ;
}


function computeDistance(startCoords , destCoords){
 var startLatRads = degreesToRadians (startCoords.latitude);
 var startLongRads = degreesToRadians (startCoords.longitude);
 var destLatRads = degreesToRadians (destCoords.latitude);
 var destLongRads = degreesToRadians (destCoords.longitude);

 var Radius = 6371 ;

 var distance = Math.acos(Math.sin(startLatRads) * Math.sin(destLatRads) +
   Math.cos(startLatRads) * Math.cos(destLatRads) *
   Math.cos(startLongRads - destLongRads)) * Radius;
 return distance ;
}

function degreesToRadians (degrees) {
 var radians = (degrees * Math.PI) / 180 ;
 return radians;
}


function displayLocation (position) {
 var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
 var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
 
 var div = document.getElementById("accurateLocation");
 div.innerHTML = "your latitude is: " + latitude + " and your longitude is :" + longitude ;

 var km = computeDistance(position.coords , ourCoords) ;
 var distance = document.getElementById("distance") ;
 distance.innerHTML = " You are " + km + " km away from the headquarter" ; 
 showMap(position.coords); 
} 

var map ;

function showMap(coords){
 var googleLatAndLong = new google.maps.LatLng (coords.latitude , coords.longitude);

 var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 10 ,
  center: googleLatAndLong,
 };

 var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
 map = new google.maps.Map (mapDiv , mapOptions);
}
```

```html
<body>
<center>
 <h2 id ="accurateLocation" ></h2>
 <div id="distance"></div>
 <div id="map"></div>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting a blank map drawn on the page?

Comment: no. no map is drawn at all.

Comment: I see, you are only calling `getMyLocation()` onload. No other function is called. You need to call `showMap()` eventually

Comment: please read the code. onload  getMyLocation() function is called which contains the call to  showMap (position.coords) function

Comment: most of the functions are called in the displayLocation(position) function